# Index a DataFrame using two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I'm trying to get a subset of a DataFrame based on two conditions.

Here my simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(48),
                    index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01',
                    periods=48, 
                    freq='1800S'))
```

I'd now like to get all values that are in the timerange t > 08:00 and t < 22:00, thus I tried:

```
result = test[test.index.hour>8 & test.index.hour<22]
```

I then get the `ValueError that the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous, use a.any() or a.all()` - and here I'm out of luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need need to put brackets around the two arrays before you use the element-wise `&`:

```
(test.index.hour > 8) & (test.index.hour < 22)
```

The `&` operator has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than the comparison operators in that expression, which leads to the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that answer is so obvious, it hurts... . I lost sight of the forrest for the trees... .

Comment: No problem - it's easy to overlook these things.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 simple solutions :

- First: enclose your conditions into braces like 
  `(test.index.hour > 8) & (test.index.hour<22)`
  due to operator & precedence
- Second : use  [the query function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

Comment: well, that they changed the precedence in the query function tells me, I'm not the only one struggling with this (rather simple) problem... . Gives my soul at leat a bit of peace :)